# ¿Cómo dar formato al código en dreamweaver?

Tags: php, dreamweaver

Tengo un código y no se como ordenarlo. No encuentro la opción.

```
    while ($nombre_fruta = current($array)) {
    if ($nombre_fruta == 'manzana') {
        echo key($array).'<br />';
    }
    next($array);
}
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con ordenarlo o dar formato?

Comment: Identar el codigo, para no confundirme con los cierres de llaves

Comment: Hasta la última versión que usé (creo que DW6), no indenta el código automáticamente (sólo el html y css). Para hacerlo deberías buscar un plugin. Podés probar con `Comandos -> Aplicar formato de origen` ... Pero no creo que te guste el resultado.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes esta página para colocar bien el código de forma que se pueda leer bien. (http://jsbeautifier.org/)
Para php: (http://phpbeautifier.com/)
http://www.cleancss.com/php-beautify/

Comment: jsbeautifier.org es para JS ósea javascript... y no sirve para PHP... además pregunta para el programa DW (Dreamweaver).. y la verdad no entiendo como no han cerrado aún la pregunta...